# Why Ruby is returning different timezones for different years?

Tags: ruby, date, timezone, timezone-offset

My timezone is IST, +0530.
It shows the correct zone if I pass arguments with recent years:

```
Time.new('2000', '02', '29')    # => 2000-02-29 00:00:00 +0530
```

But the zone changes for years like these:

```
Time.new('1000', '01', '29')    # => 1000-01-29 00:00:00 +0553
Time.new('1943')                # => 1943-01-01 00:00:00 +0630
Time.new('1871')                # => 1871-01-01 00:00:00 +0521
```

To find out the previous dates, I created a loop:

```
puts 2_200.times.map { |i| Time.new(i.to_s) }
```

As I can see for the years in the future, the zone is +0530, but for past centuries, the zone is sometime differs!

Why does the zone differ in the same system?

Comment: Timezones change historically. Not uncommon during war periods for instance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_India#Recorded_history

Comment: I actually didn't know that. BTW, are the values hard coded into Ruby?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database

Comment: @Mat, that makes for very interesting reading. One [footnote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database#cite_note-34) (at the Tz_database link) caught my eye, concerning a threatened copyright lawsuit.

Comment: Anyways, it's not Ruby, the date command in my system prints the same output!! `date -d 1943/11/24 +%z` prints +0630...

Comment: [Why is subtracting these two times (in 1927) giving a strange result?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6841333/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is subtracting these two times (in 1927) giving a strange result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result)

Comment: I have no idea about Java. Java is not Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the zone differ in the same system?

Because time zones change over time.